# Attach (import?) a resource to a cloudformation stack using templates

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a api gateway that was created using the aws console a long time ago, and now I would like to attach that gateway to a cloudformation stack using the template. I know the resource's logical ID, but I'm having a hard time passing the logical Id to the stack during my update operation. Is this possible without using the console? I'm aware of the console functionality to import resources to a stack, I'm trying to achieve this using a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some misconception on how does [Importing Existing Resources Into a Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html) work.

**Change set**

You can't perform stack import operation from inside a template. You have to use **CLI** or console for that, because you need to generate **a change set** for the import. This is an external operation to your templates available through **CLI** or Console.

**Available resources**

Not all resources can be imported to CFN. Luckily, `AWS::ApiGateway::Resource` is one of those that [can](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html).

**Importing templates**

To perform the importing action, you have to **prepare your own template** defining a resource `AWS::ApiGateway::Resource` which fully describes existing API resource. All attributes in the template file you define **must match** those of the existing API resources.

In other words, importing operation does not generate any templates (or yaml/json) files for you. Its largely **manual operation** involving writing a template and performing a change set.

**Link**

A good resource on how importing can be done **using CLI**, is the following tutorial:

- [Import an Existing Resource into a Stack Using the AWS CloudFormation Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html)

Hope this helps.

I don't know what kind of "hard times" you have (its not described in the question), thus I'm unable to provide more precised info to help you.

Comment: That makes sense, I figured it was one of those "admin" operations not meant to be templatized, since it's a one-time changeset.

Comment: @rodmunera yes. importing resources is useful, but it works in a way  people usually don't expect. Thus the misconceptions.

Comment: Thank you Marcin, after playing around with our sandbox account, using the console worked and was able to make subsequent updates to the gateway using the new template and the new stack. I've marked your answer as accepted :)